# Snaking toilet: regular maintenance or only if issue?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

My partner and I live in a small (7-unit) condo building and want to make sure that we are maintaining our unit according to what are standard practices. One question we have is whether snaking our toilet is maintenance item or whether this is something that is typically only done if an issue arises.

Is it standard practice to snake your toilet regularly, or is this only done if we have concerns about our toilet/plumbing?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure there are differing opinions on this but snaking a toilet that is used "normally" should not be a periodic maintenance procedure.  In normal use nothing should be there for the snake to dislodge and it can cause scratches and other wear-and-tear on the fixtures and the plumbing.

Now by "normal" I mean that the only things that should go down the toilet are bodily wastes and normal amount of toilet paper.  Anything else runs the risk of clogging.

If you have some special considerations or there is a known issue with the plumbing, then you might want to do it without a clear clogging issue but a better approach would be to get that problem resolved.

Comment: thank you for your input! Would love to hear others' thoughts (same or differing) on this, but yes it is just normal use. Just bodily waste and TP.

Comment: Snaking is fixing not maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

The approximate frequency for snaking a toilet is: never.

I inherited the appropriate sort of drain auger (left behind in a house we bought) but I've never actually used it, and never needed to. So far a plunger (sometimes aided by a bit of dish soap) has proved entirely adequate (and that is also "fixing, not maintenance.")

"Normally" simply flushing should be all that's needed. If your toilet clogs frequently, there's a problem that should be resolved (sometimes plumbing, sometimes human - I once put up a notice in a cooperative house requesting that folks flush after every 10 feet of paper...someone liked to use a LOT of paper.) Plunging was still sufficient to clear that.

Comment: Small children in the home = greater chance of utilizing a plunger. Amazing what they throw down there. That and women flushing sanitary items inconsiderately. Tough being a landlord.